# Extract Menu from String

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract a menu from a string whenever there is one.

```
recipe ABC: Quelle bonne idC)e!
L: 33348, C: 2130

1 Like

2 Comment

3 Next

4 See Comments
# Home
```

Since I am new to regex, I tried this for a start:

```
  If Regex.IsMatch(text, "(\d\w*\n)*") Then

  End If
```

And it returned true.

Am I doing this right?

I want to be able to extract the menu whenever there is one. Menus don't have a pre-defined format. So I used whatever starts with number `\d` followed by alphanumeric character `\w` and new line `\n`.

After regex returning true, how can I extract the text that did match the regex?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your expected output? I think you mean this `@"\b\d\w*(?=\n)"`

Comment: Rather than checking `Regex.IsMatch`, you could directly use `Regex.Match`

Comment: if menus don't have a pre-defined format then what is the rule to check if string contains menu? Is `1 Like; 2 Comment; 3 Menu;` a menu?

Comment: @ASh The rule is for it to start with a number, then characters and then a new line  - Repeated several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex `(?sm).*(?=^\d+\s+\p{L}+[\r\n])` that is taking everything from the beginning and up to a line (due to `^`) that starts with a number (`\d+`), then some spaces (`\s+`), then some letters (`\p{L}`), then a newline (`[\r\n]`):

```
var txt ="Lorem ipsum:amet, consectetur adipiscing elit!!\r\nL: 33348, C: 2130\r\n\r\n1 Next\r\n\r\n2 Forward\r\n\r\n3 Last\r\n\r\n4 See more";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?sm).*?(?=^\d+\s+\p{L}+[\r\n])");
var res = rx.Match(txt).Value;
```

However, I believe your menu always starts with `1` at the line start, and all menu items are generally capitalized. That is why I suggest using [another regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fsm).*(%3F%3D%5E1%5Cs%2B%5Cp%7BLu%7D)&i=Lorem%20ipsum%3Aamet%2C%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit!!%0D%0AL%3A%2033348%2C%20C%3A%202130%0D%0A%0D%0A1%20Next%0D%0A%0D%0A2%20Forward%0D%0A%0D%0A3%20Last%0D%0A%0D%0A4%20See%20more&o=sm) to reflect the following conditions: take all until a line that starts with `1` followed by some space(s), and then by an uppercase letter:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?sm).*(?=^1\s+\p{Lu})");
```

Or, you can try to split the string into lines, and check if a line starts with `1`.

```
var out2 = string.Join("\r\n",txt.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).TakeWhile(p => !p.StartsWith("1 ")).ToList());
```

Results:

[image] [image]

Comment: I think you cannot use the `start with any number` condition, it is unsafe. I'd use the initial version of `var rx = new Regex(@"(?sm).*(?=^1\s+\p{Lu})");`. Please check.

Comment: Glad to help. In case you want to see the regex in action, here is a [link to the demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fsm).*(%3f%3d%5e1%5cs%2b%5cp%7bLu%7d)&i=Lorem+ipsum%3aamet%2c+consectetur+adipiscing+elit!!%0d%0aL%3a+33348%2c+C%3a+2130%0d%0a%0d%0a1+Next%0d%0a%0d%0a2+Forward%0d%0a%0d%0a3+Last%0d%0a%0d%0a4+See+more&o=sm).

Comment: The text outside the menu might have string in the following format: 1 followed by space and Uppercase letter. That's why it's not so safe that I use it. But I'll use the first option. Thanks!

Comment: I see. As a final remark I should mention that the 1st regex actually will match much more substrings in your input, I am just using `.Match()` to return the 1st match. Best regards.

Comment: Is there a way to check the count of matches and take the last one?

Comment: Last non-empty match can be obtained with `var last_match = rx.Matches(txt).Cast<Match>().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value)).LastOrDefault();`, or just the final match value can be obtained with `var last_match = rx.Matches(txt).Cast<Match>().LastOrDefault().Value;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `isMatch`, which will return only the information "Did the pattern match anything"?

You should use something like this :

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d\w*\n)*");
    Match match = regex.Match(yourText);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
```

**Disclaimer** : As your question was not about your expression itself, I haven't checked what it does. You haven't asked help on that part so I didn't give any.